# Get a list of installed programs with application icons

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I need to get a list of installed program on local machine with **application icons**. Below is the code snippet that am using to get the list of installed program and installed directory path.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of installed software and, if known, the software's install path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string Getinstalledsoftware()
    {
        //Declare the string to hold the list:
        string Software = null;

        //The registry key:
        string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey))
        {
            //Let's go through the registry keys and get the info we need:
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //If the key has value, continue, if not, skip it:
                        if (!(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == null))
                        {
                            //Is the install location known?
                            if (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") == null)
                                Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - Install path not known\n"; //Nope, not here.
                            else
                                Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - " + sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") + "\n"; //Yes, here it is...
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //No, that exception is not getting away... :P
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Software;
    }
```

Now the issue is how i can get the installed application icon ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more thing that above code also includes window updates, how can i exclude those programs ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To determine if its an update, there will be a key called `IsMinorUpgrade`. This is present and set to a `1` for updates. If it's `0` or not present, then it's not an update.

To get an icon from an executable, use this code:

**VB**:

```vb
Public Function IconFromFilePath(filePath As String) As Icon 
    Dim result As Icon = Nothing 
    Try 
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath) 
    Catch ''# swallow and return nothing. You could supply a default Icon here as well 
    End Try 
    Return result 
End Function
```

**C#**:

```cs
public Icon IconFromFilePath(string filePath)
{
    Icon result = null;
    try {
        result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
    } catch { }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i'm using "DisplayIcon" key to get the icon against the installed program but got different results when compared to Add Remove Program Utility available in WIN XP Control panel. Any suggestions ?

Comment: That is wierd. I do not have any ideas, but I'll see if I can research this more

Answer (score 0):

To extract icon of installed windows application first we need to figure out the location of icon for the installed windows application. This information is stored in registry at following locations -

1. Key name - HEKY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
   Value - DisplayIcon
2. Key name - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products{productID}
   Value - ProductIcon

For more detail and code to get application icons -
http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2015/06/extract-icons-of-installed-windows_17.html