# Get DisplayIcon for installed programs

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to get the icons for the installed software on a computer.

The installed software list is populated from this registry paths:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

The duplicates are excluded based on DisplayName.

Now I try to get the icon from the key DisplayIcon. If it's present.
The values in DisplayIcon differ from software to software. Some example are as fallows:

- D:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\FileZilla.exe
- C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller\OSETUP.DLL,1
- D:\Program Files\Fiddler2\IE_Toolbar.ico
- dfshim.dll,2
- D:\Program Files\Winamp\winamp.exe,0
- etc\git.ico

For all of this examples I can take the icon. If the InstallLocation + DisplayIcon is not the real source, I can search the InstallLocation for the DisplayIcon name(ex: DisplayIcon for GetDataBackFor* is gdbnt.exe so I search this and if is found i take his icon)

The problem is how other apps like revo or windows uninstaller take the icon of apps that don't have the DisplayIcon key. They have only the InstallLocation with the root directory. They search for ico's or exe's in that location? What if they are more than one executable and the name of this executable doesn't look like DisplayName? How they are pooling the icon from the main executable if in registry there is no such info?
Examples of such apps are Google Earth, Apple Software Update, etc.

Comment: This seems like a potential duplicate of [Get a list of installed programs with application icons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2907565/62576).

Comment: You don't understand the question or I'm explaining it to bad. The issue is about those programs that don't have any information about the icon(executable, icons, only one executable in InstallLocation).

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question. :-) In the examples you show, it's the indicated icon: for FileZilla.exe, the first icon found; for Office, the icon at index 1 in OSETUP.DLL; for Fiddler2, it's the icon file `IE_Toolbar.ico' itself; for Winamp, it's the first icon found (index 0) in Winamp.exe; the final one is for the icon file `git.ico` found in the `etc\` folder under the install path.

Comment: Exactly, for those scenarios I can take the icons. But there are some programs like google earth that don't have any info that will help to get the icon in the registry.Anyhow revo uninstaller and windows uninstaller can take the icon somehow...and I don't know how.

Comment: Perhaps they use the icon of the uninstaller binary, if no specific icon is listed?

Comment: Did you find a solution andySF? I'm currently in the same situation.

Comment: This is my class for getting installed programs. It's not the perfect solution but time was an issue. Maybe it will help you. https://gist.github.com/andySF/19f3569b50db18095a3d

Comment: @andySF any update on this? Did you solve it eventually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find information about icons of installed product from following location
This information is stored in registry at Installer\product key also along with Uninstall-

Key name - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products{productID}

Value - ProductIcon

From here we can get the icons of installed application. 
For more detail http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2015/06/extract-icons-of-installed-windows_17.html